# Electron - Including HTML files in other HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Hi I am new to electron so i don't know how to do this simple thing... also tried searching before asking but was not able to find proper solution.

```
// HEADER
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    // some css files
</head>
<body>
// END HEADER


// INDEX.HTML
<div class="wrapper"></div>
// END INDEX.HTML


// FOOTER
    // some scripts using require and script taglike 
   require('renderer.js');
</body>
</html>
// END FOOTER
```

> These are three parts of my file header, main content, footer ... I want to keep header and footer in different files so that i can include them in other files too so that all the pages can get same header and footer.
>   
>   In php I used to do include("header.php"); Something Like this I want to do in Electron

**I Want to include header.html and footer.html in index.html file**

Please try to give the easiest solution

Comment: Electron is basically a browser window; what you are trying to do requires a server though. I'd advise to use a JS framework like React or Angular instead.

Comment: You don't need a framework for that, all you need is a templating engine like handlebars. They are easy to get started with.

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988855/6577664?

Comment: @Mike They are loading external file into a div ... but how can i load full header.html file which includes css and all into div... I think it is not possible

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks But I only know jquery ... No react no angular